# setTestClasses in TestNG does not work with setParallel?

Tags: java, maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

So I want to make my testNG classes run in parallel. I also am generating these testNG classes using a factory like so:

```
    @Factory
    public Object[] makeTests() {
        Object[] tests = new Object[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            tests[i] = new SampleTestClass(i);
        }
        return tests;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestNG tng = new TestNG();

        tng.setTestClasses(new Class[] {TestEngine.class});
        tng.run();

    }
```

I want to run these test classes in parallel. But when I try using tng.setParallel(XmlSuite.ParallelMode.CLASSES), it doesn't work. Neither does the maven surefire plugin, when I specify:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>classes</parallel>
                    <threadCount>10</threadCount>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Is there a different way of parallelizing for this way of setting test classes?

EDIT: Solution found, it should be ParallelMode.INSTANCES.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with Maven Surefire. The only thing that worked for parallel execution was:

```
<property>
    <name>suitethreadpoolsize</name>
    <value>16</value>
</property>
```

property, part of the maven-surefire properties.